# How to pass encoded Amazon s3 signed URL in python curl Postfields?

Tags: python, curl, amazon-s3, pycurl

I need to pass an amazon s3 signed URL to my python cURL function. The signed url have some special characters as '%' which is passed to the cURL POSTFIELDS and after the processing I am getting 500 Internal Server error. Is there a way to pass the POSTFIELDS in encoded format so cURL can process it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import urllib
import pycurl

def urlconvert:
  wrapper = {'filename':p} # p is the amazon s3 signed url
  c = pycurl.Curl()
  c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url) #url is the url for curl request
  c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
  post_args = urllib.urlencode(wrapper)
  c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, post_args)
```